# Open Java Clip File Before Actually Playing it?

Tags: java, audio, load, jbutton, clip

I have a button that plays this code when pressed:

```
public void music() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/audio/InGame01.mid");
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But, not only is the sound delayed (I'm assuming its because it has to read the sound file, and then play it), the button also becomes frozen until it finishes reading the sound clip. Is there a simple way to open the audio clip before the button is actually pressed, so that it already has it loaded? (clip.open(audioIn) is what I'm talking about.)

This is where the method is called(Button Listener):

```
try {
                music();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: that's not a "sound clip". it's a midi file, which is basically just a series of instructions for what instruments/notes to play. it's not just some PCM samples you're throwing at a speaker. it's essentially a "program" to "play" a piece of music.

Comment: @MarcB Ok, but is there a way to execute "clip.open(audioIn)" from another class? If that wouldn't solve it, then how could I prevent the delay?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-synth.html   as for the delay, pre-load it in a "silent" player so that all the necessary setup is done before you actually need it?